# AMD torque wrench failed, trashing the TR4 socket on my motherboard. Is there a path to recourse?

Tags: cpu, processor-socket, torque, threadripper

After reading instructions, and watching several video demonstrations, including AMD's own, I installed a new Threadripper CPU into the TR4 socket of a new ASRock X399 Tiachi motherboard. Unfortunately, the torque wrench that came with the CPU failed -- meaning that it never stopped torquing. (There should have been a telltale click as the wrench slipped, upon reaching the nominal torque.) As a result, the socket screws tightened until the socket made an unpleasant scraping sound. When I unscrewed the socket and inspected, it was clear that hundreds of the pins had been bent.

Has anybody had a similar experience, and more relevant, any suggestions for getting recourse from AMD for their wrench's failure? There is no indication from casual inspection that any of the pads on the CPU itself have been damaged, so I couldn't ask for a replacement of that.

Absent recourse, is it practical to find and install a replacement TR4 socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this article from top to bottom. It does not leave any room for hope

https://laurentschoice.com/2017/diy/diy-install-threadripper-tr4-socket/

> Quote "And having 4094 pins does represent 4094 occasions to
>   irreversibly damage your board"

Comment: Thanks for the helpful article @John.

Looks like no amount of careful prep goes unpunished.

Comment: Yes.  I looked carefully on your behalf and this was the best I could find.